# Discrete distributions; find E(X)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

For each of the following distributions, find:

- $\mu=\mathsf E(X)$
- $\mathsf E[X(X-1)]$ and
- $σ^2=\mathsf E[X(X-1)]+\mathsf E(X)-\mu^2$:

> a) $f(x)= \frac{3! }{ x!(3-x)! }(\frac 1 4)^x (\frac 3 4)^{3-x}, x\in\{0,1,2,3\}$
>
> b) $f(x)=(\frac{4! }{ x!(4-x)! })(\frac 1 2)^4, x\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$

Anyone know how to go about solving problems like this? Thanks in advance for tips/solutions

Comment: So you want to find the mean and the variance.
For the mean multiply f(x) by x and sum over the domain.
For the variance multiply $f(x)$ by $x^2$ and sum over the domain and then subtract the mean squared. 
So plug in 0 for x then multiply by 0. Then plug in 1 for x and then multiply by 1. Keep doing it till you hit 3.
Then sum them all up and you will the expectation.

For the variance you would need to do the same thing expect multiply by $x^2$. Then sum up all those values and subtract the mean squared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the expectation of a function $g$ of a discrete random variable $X$, with probability mass distribution function $f$ measured over domain $\cal D$ is defined as:

$$\mathsf E[g(X)] = \sum_{x\in\mathcal D} g(x) f(x)$$

Thus 
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E[X] &= \sum_{x\in\mathcal D} x f(x) \\[2ex] \mathsf E[X(X-1)] &= \sum_{x\in\mathcal D} x(x-1) f(x)\end{align}$$

You have the density functions and domains of the random variables to sum over.  Substitute and solve.